# Understanding this solution to solving $\cosh z = w$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and fixed $w$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\cosh z = w$.
Then 
$$e^{2z} - 2we^z + 1 = 0\\ e^z= \frac{2w \pm PV\sqrt{4w^2 - 4}}{2} \\ = w \pm PV\sqrt{w^2 - 1}$$ 
where $PV\sqrt{w^2 - 1}$ is the principle value of the function $\sqrt{w^2 - 1}$.

Hence, $z = \mathrm{Log}(w\pm PV\sqrt{w^2-1})+ 2\pi i k$.

I understand up to here, but then they do the following:
Note that $(w+PV\sqrt{w^2 - 1})(w-PV\sqrt{w^2 - 1}) = 1$, we can conclude then that
$z = \pm\mathrm{Log}(w + PV\sqrt{w^2-1})+ 2\pi i k$.

I'm not sure how to see this consequence, or what the product being equal to $1$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the reference to principal value in this context is ridiculous. It would be better to say that $\sqrt{w^2-1}$ is *some* square root of $w^2-1$.

Now, concerning your question, what happens is that\begin{multline*}\left(w+PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)\left(w-PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)=1\Longrightarrow\\\Longrightarrow\operatorname{Log}\left(w+PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)+\operatorname{Log}\left(w-PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)=0\end{multline*}and so $\operatorname{Log}\left(w-PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)=-\operatorname{Log}\left(w+PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)$. Therefore$$\operatorname{Log}\left(w\pm PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right)=\pm\operatorname{Log}\left(w+PV\sqrt{w^2-1}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you. They use $PV$ in front of any possible multi-valued function.  
What would happen if the product was equal to $-1$ instead?  
I ask this because doing this for the similar equation $\sinh z = w$, we get $e^z = w \pm PV\sqrt{w^2 + 1}$, so the product of the two give a result of $-1$. The answer says that this means $z = \mathrm{Log}(w+PV\sqrt{w^2+1}) + 2\pi i k$ or $z = -\mathrm{Log}(w+PV\sqrt{w^2 + 1}) + 2\pi i k + \pi i$ (an extra $\pi i$?). I don't understand this, and thought it'd be similar to the first question.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Remember that $\exp(\pi i)=-1$.

Comment: Ahh I see now thank you. Just a slightly unrelated question about the PV comment; is there a good resource online to learn all about principal values of functions when solving equations such as this?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Not that I am aware of.